# background removal using emgucv

Tags: c#, emgucv

How to remove background from a live video feed using emgucv. I need some thing like this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOEuE3D88b0). The only thing I want is a moving object or a human. i tried motion detection but didn't achieve the performance level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this if only background and light conditions are stable. first take the background image. then take the differences between background image and video frames. in the end, mask the zero value pixels. in other words:

(bg: background image, cf: current frame, ri: result image)

1. ri = bg - cf
2. threshold: make the zero value pixels black, and the others white. other pixels belong to moving objects (the men in the video)
3. find white blobs
4. mask those white blobs on the cf
5. past those masks on any other background you want

do these steps for every frame of video

Comment: @LingboTang you mean "what is a threshold" or "what is the threshold you talk about"? if first, a dictionary can help; else, i've already explained it :)

Comment: Actually I was trying to ask how do you find the white blobs in code, what specific function in emguCV does that job?

Comment: @LingboTang for EmguCV 3.1.0+ you can use Emgu.CV.Cvb.CvBlobDetector class. first create an object of this class and then use its "Detect" method. This will detect all seperate white pixel stacks and label them all. you can also get their area, bounding box, contour, centroid etc.